# can you reorder three strategies Spring MVC uses to determine the content requested

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filepath

I know that spring has three strategies to determine the content requested and returning the corresponding type. and spring use these three strategies in order to detect. which are

1. PathExtension  (file extension in url)
2. pathParameter
3. Accept Headers

can I reorder these so spring will check  Accept Header first ? like

1. Accept Headers
2. PathExtension
3. pathParameter

Comment: If result will be same, why do you need reorder request processing?

Comment: @KenBekov, i have a mapping that would prefer pathExtension checking on, and a mapping that url contains file extension in url that only wants to get JSON returned. with the default order, the mapping that needs pathExtension works fine, but the one that dont wants it throws error and because the order, I cant use accept headers to override the path checking. sorry for my poor english, hope it make sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you will need custom `ContentNegotiationManager`. Default `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` has fixed order of strategies and suggests instantiation of your own `ContentNegotiationManager` when you want to customize the order, as simple as

```
new ContentNegotiationManager(strategies);
```

where `strategies` is a list of strategies in proper order.

But I believe it's easier to extend `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` just overriding `afterPropertiesSet` method where strategies get created and ordered.

```
public class MyCustomContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean extends ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean {
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        List<ContentNegotiationStrategy> strategies = new ArrayList<ContentNegotiationStrategy>();

        if (!this.ignoreAcceptHeader) {
            strategies.add(new HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy());
        }

        if (this.favorPathExtension) {
            PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy strategy;
            if (this.servletContext != null && !isUseJafTurnedOff()) {
                strategy = new ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy(
                        this.servletContext, this.mediaTypes);
            }
            else {
                strategy = new PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy(this.mediaTypes);
            }
            strategy.setIgnoreUnknownExtensions(this.ignoreUnknownPathExtensions);
            if (this.useJaf != null) {
                strategy.setUseJaf(this.useJaf);
            }
            strategies.add(strategy);
        }

        if (this.favorParameter) {
            ParameterContentNegotiationStrategy strategy =
                    new ParameterContentNegotiationStrategy(this.mediaTypes);
            strategy.setParameterName(this.parameterName);
            strategies.add(strategy);
        }

        if (this.defaultNegotiationStrategy != null) {
            strategies.add(this.defaultNegotiationStrategy);
        }

        this.contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManager(strategies);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this factory bean in your spring configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="com.yourcompany.MyCustomContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean"/>
```

### Annotation-based Configuration

In order to configure `ContentNegotiationManager` in annotation-based configuration, remove `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` or  `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` with your configuration class. Then you want to override [`mvcContentNegotiationManager` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L326) of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. That method is responsible for instantiation of `ContentNegotiationManager`.

Don't forget to add `@Bean` annotation to overriden method.

Comment: this is extaclty what i was looking for, I was not able to find the detail of how to do this. thank you very much. I have not try it yet tho. i will make it the answer once I have it work.

Comment: how do I use this factory bean in spring configuration with Java instead of xml ?